# How to do like this list using <li> and CSS?

Tags: html, css

i want to make an stylized unordered list like the following, but i don't want it to be completely divs, i want to use the `<li>` & `<ul>` tags and maybe a div if it's necessary.

[image]

Any sample code to make like this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, this looks like:

```
<ul class="rated-list">
    <li>
        <span class="rating">1086</span>
        <a href="/foo.html">Why Don't …</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can then use CSS to give the `span` and `a` fixed widths and float them left.

Alternatively, you could make only the `span` fixed-and-floated and give the link a `margin-left` equal to the `span`'s width, plus whatever padding you want.  Come to think of it, that's probably a better solution!  :-)

Comment: And ? `-moz-border-radius`/ `webkit-border-radius` for the slightly rounded corners.

Comment: @Pekka and real border-radius for Opera and future up-to-date browsers.

Comment: @Pekka —  Heh, with my eyes and on this monitor, I can't even see any rounding!  Yes, you could either use CSS border rounding or (if the height will be fixed as well) a `background-image` to make it IE-friendly as well.

Comment: there is actually border-radius on top-left and bottom-right.

Answer (score 0):

Ben's markup for the list looks similiar to what i would put together. I've used his markup and provided a some CSS file to get something similiar to your screenshot:

Markup:

```
<ul class="rated-list">
        <li>
            <span class="rating">1086</span>
            <a href="/foo.html">Why Don't…</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rating">1087</span>
            <a href="/foo.html">We try...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rating">1088</span>
            <a href="/foo.html">A little...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="rating">1089</span>
            <a href="/foo.html">CSS?</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    color:#958C51;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:83%;
    font-size-adjust:none;
    font-style:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ul.rated-list
{
    list-style:none;
    width:300px;
    border-top:solid 1px #DDD;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.rated-list li 
{
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px 0px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #DDD;
    vertical-align:top;
}
span.rating
{
    background:Transparent url('http://cotnet.diggstatic.com/img/shade-news.gif') no-repeat top left;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 10px;
    width:32px;
    height:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
ul.rated-list li a
{
    width:240px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#517197;
}
```

I've also set a little initial body style and decided to draw the DIGG span background image for simplicity. You'd obviously just reference a local web site file in production.

Hope it helps some people out. :-)